# SSL authentication at website

Tags: authentication, iis, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

I need to make something like ssl certificate authentication at website. As far as I understand my task I need to get user's ssl certificate and send it to server what will decide can user be authenticated or not. 
How can I get user's SSL by javascript and send it to server? Is it possible at all? Or maybe my approach is wrong or I do not understand my task correctly.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: windows 2008 R2 Enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe my solution will be useful for somebody. At IIS server configuration we need to check require users certificates checkbox. Than user when opens site will be asked for a certificate form personal certificates storage. 
After if public certificate can be accessed from a Request object (c#) at server. From it we can get user's details and allow or deny login

Comment: Client-auth SSL is a very reasonable approach that gives high assurance of the identity of clients as well as servers, provided it is acceptable to force clients to have certificates in the first place (which is why it is rare outside of intranets).